# AHK IfWinActive with chrome app

Tags: windows-7, automation, autohotkey

I have a script that opens up google calendar in a separate window using chrome *app=MyURL*

```
#k::
run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1
winactivate
return
```

The problem is that if I have one calendar window open, and hit #k, then it opens up a new one. I would like the program to open up the existing one if it exists. I suspect this can be done with **IfWinActive** but I have no experience with AHK (or any programming langauge).

Answer (score 2):

I use my own function that implements `IfWinActive`. Here is an example:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#k::ShowStart("Calendar", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromea.exe  --app=https://www.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1")

ShowStart(title, exe)
{
    IfWinExist, %title%
        WinActivate
    else
    {
        Run, %exe%,, UseErrorLevel
        If ErrorLevel
        {
            Msgbox, File Not Found
            Return
        }
        WinActivate
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, I just needed to move "SetTitleMatchMode Mode, 2" inside the "ShowStart" function.

ShowStart(title, exe)
{
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
...
   }